# How to decipher EXC_BAD_ACCESS on memcpy assembly instruction?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, x86-64, mov

I am debugging an application during which I encountered a runtime error in a module for which I don't have symbols. I looked into the assembly code for it and have identified the code line which is throwing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error:

```
    0x7fff204dd0a5 <+37>:  movq   %rdx, %rcx
    0x7fff204dd0a8 <+40>:  cld    
->  0x7fff204dd0a9 <+41>:  rep    movsb (%rsi), %es:(%rdi)
    0x7fff204dd0ab <+43>:  popq   %rbp
```

Assembly instructions one frame below:

```
    0x10c2641b0 <+96>:  callq  0x10c264382  ; symbol stub for: memcpy
->  0x10c2641b5 <+101>: movl   $0x0, -0x4(%rbp)
    0x10c2641bc <+108>: movl   -0x4(%rbp), %eax
```

The lines marked with an arrow are throwing the error. I am very new to assembly language and am not able to figure out why this error is being thrown.
As far as I understand, `movl` instruction moves 32 bits of data from the second variable into the first. Is the error being thrown because `$0x0` is a null address? I am not sure because `$` indicates a variable and not a constant

**Edit:**
I got to know that rsi and rdi are source and destination index registers and they are specially used for memcpy implementation. I was able to read the values of these registers. It turns out there is access violation reading the value at address of rsi register.
Does this mean that source memory is getting corrupted? What are the possible reasons for this to happen?

Comment: Put a breakpoint at `0x7FFF204FFA9` and look at registers `RSI,RDI,RCX`. Memory addressed with `RSI` (**source**) up to `RSI+RCX-1` should be allocated and **readable**. **Destination** memory addressed with `RDI` up to `RDI+RCX-1` should be allocated as **writable**, which probably isn't and throws an error. Consult memory allocation with ELF program headers.

Comment: @vitsoft I checked and found that the source register memory is throwing "memory read failed" error ! Is there any possible reason for this ?

Comment: Possible reason is that `RSI` points to an invalid address, perhaps `memcpy` was invoked with wrong argument. `$0x0` indicates immediate constant literal value in [AT&T](https://csiflabs.cs.ucdavis.edu/~ssdavis/50/att-syntax.htm), i.e. zero or NULL when treated as a pointer.

Comment: It doesn't mean the source *memory* got corrupted, it means the *pointer* got corrupted somehow so it's not pointing to valid source memory.  Presumably the pointer was stored in memory at once point.  (It's also possible this copy is a use-after-free or something, in which case yes you could say the source memory was "corrupted" by being unmapped.)  You're trying to memcpy from an invalid pointer, so the possible reasons for that are no different from any other case of trying to deref a bad pointer.

Comment: The arrow in the stack frame above is the instruction *after* the call to `memcpy`, i.e. the next one to be executed after `memcpy` returns.  It has not been executed yet, so it is not related to your crash.  Anyway, it is a move of the literal number 0 into stack location `[rbp-4]`; that in itself cannot crash unless `rbp` is corrupted or the stack is extremely messed up.  Look instead at the instructions that *precede* the call to `memcpy` (not included in your snippet); they may show how the arguments passed to `memcpy` were obtained.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, it turned out to be an issue of use-after-free only ! I figured it out using Address sanitizer in XCode. It's an amazing feature really.